# Can you change your login info on Pokemon Go?

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go

I had to update the software on my phone last night after playing Pokémon Go for the first time. This morning I'm trying to login and it is not recognizing my Gmail password. I tried the password recovery multiple times and that didn't work so I created a new Gmail account. So now my question is, can I change my login info on Pokémon Go to my new Gmail account? I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. I changed my password and then I couldn't log back in. Delete the app then reinstall it. Then log back in using your account with your new password. You'll be good to go. Right where you left off.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to contact the Support here https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us

There doesn't seem to be a default-form for this request though.